Extracting first paragraph from node in org-mode and convert to text
I am trying to extract text from orgmode through elisp code. I have item as a node of my buffer, and I would like to extract the text for the first paragraph below the headline.
That is the document looks like this:
* Section 
** Hello
** World
What a beautiful day
*** Some other stuff

item corresponds to the node with headline World and I would like to get "What a beautiful day". Additionnally, if that makes it safer (as only the raw text is important) I can encapsulate "What a beautiful day" within a source block.
I've looked at https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html and tried to extract the first child using (car (org-element-contents 'item)) but it doesn't look I'm getting anywhere.

I'm not sure exactly what you have as item, but you can go to the :contents-begin of a headline node and return the paragraph you find there, if there is one.
(defun my-first-para (item)
  "Message the first paragraph following headline ITEM, if present.
When called interactively, ITEM is the element at point."
  (interactive (list (org-element-at-point-no-context)))
  (when-let ((beg (org-element-property :contents-begin item)))
    (goto-char beg)
    (let ((el (org-element-at-point-no-context)))
      (when (eq 'paragraph (org-element-type el))
        (message
         (buffer-substring-no-properties
          (org-element-property :contents-begin el)
          (org-element-property :contents-end el)))))))


Thanks, solved my problem
